# What do I do if I accidentally uninstalled my system hard drive drivers

Tags: hard-drive, drivers, ssd, uninstall, help-files

While doing a repair , I accidentally uninstalled the driver's for my system SD hard drive, the system ran for a little bit, but then ended up crashing and has gone into a restart and does not recognize the drive, how do I recover in this situation?

Comment: See if you can get the driver from the drive manufacturer on a bootable USB and see if you can install the driver.  Otherwise you need to reinstall the OS.

Comment: That doesn't sound very good, do you think it might be possible to boot into a recovery boot disk and from there install the driver in a recovery situation? I know this is an insanely funny question, I've never done anything like this before LOL I understand if you laugh

Comment: I am thinking the manufacturer may supply a bootable USB for the driver. Booting into a recovery USB will reinstall your system.

Comment: What operating system?  On Windows the driver you uninstalled would have been built-into Windows. It should have been virtually impossible to do this without purposefully attempting to break your system by performing whatever action you performed.  You might provide specifics on what you did exactly

Comment: Did you "repair" whatever it was you were trying to? Need far more information than what's provided. OS, BIOS, bootloader, Did you manage to delete drive firmware?? WHAT does not recognise the drive? (OS, BIOS, bootloader...)

Comment: First thing to try is System Restore. If you haven't done that yet, do it.